# Lazy UITableView load

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

I load a portion of data from server and show it in UITableView. When the user scrolls tableView to the bottom of tableView (last cell), I load next portion of data and show it in new cells in tableView (add new cells).

My goal is to show in the bottom cell activity indicator while the data is loading from the server. Is there any standard beautiful and elegant way of implementation? I searched a lot, but found no answer.

Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep a BOOL `isLoadingData` in my data model that tracks when data is loading. My `tableViewController` observes this property via KVO and updates the `tableView`. I've used the following methods to show the activity indicator.

1. in `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`, if `isLoadingData = YES` return a view that contains a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and a `UILabel` indicating that data is loading. Otherwise return `nil`.
2. if `isLoadingData = YES`, in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` add additional section to the count and return `1` for this section in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` return a "loading" cell that contains a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and a `UILabel`.

Comment: I would use method 1, as it is a lot cleaner

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It really helped me! One comment - is it wright to store "isLoadingData" in data model instead of controller?